# Passing Params to a Codeigniter Library

Tags: codeigniter

I have a custom library (in application\libraries) which I can call fine, however I want to pass data from model, via the controller:
In the controller:

```
$MenuData['daily']  = $this->bookmarks_model->getDaily();

$this->load->library('MyMenu');

$menu = new MyMenu;

$data['menu'] = $menu->ShowMenu($MenuData);
```

In the MyMenu library:

```
function ShowMenu($Params)
{
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->helper('url');
$CI->config->item('base_url');
//More Code  here  
$menu .= "<li><a href='#'>Daily</a>";
$menu .= "  <ul>";
foreach($daily as $row) : 
    $menu .= "<li><a href='" .  $row->url . "' target='_blank'>" .  $row->short_title . "</a></li>";
endforeach; 
$menu .= "   </ul> ";
$menu .= "   </li>";
//More Code  here  
}
return $menu;
```

However I'm getting an undefined variable error and invalid arguments for for each.
Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: we need to see what $daily is to diagnose the "invalid arguments" for the foreach. It expects an array

Comment: Ross- there is a function which is returning an array:
function getDaily() {
        $q = $this->db->get_where('bookmarks',array('tags'=>'daily'),10);
        if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a multi-dimensional array (`$MenuData`)to the function, then trying to pass one of the second level arrays (`$MenuData['daily']`) inside the MD array to the foreach loop without referencing the first level.  Instead of :

```
foreach($daily as $row) :
```

Try:

```
foreach($Params['daily'] as $row) :
```

Or before your foreach loop declare a variable to hold the second level array:

```
$daily = $Params['daily']
foreach($daily as $row):
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry but it may just be me. This `.=` means concatenate at the end of the string already found in the variable but you haven't used it before now. So should this line:

```
$menu .= "<li><a href='#'>Daily</a>";
```

be:

```
$menu = "<li><a href='#'>Daily</a>";
```

Comment: Thanks Matt - this isn't the problem as I have used it before in the code '//More Code  here'. Didn't want to post the whole lot. Thanks for the answer